# When I press C-M-g in emacs inside iterm2 terminal, it sends C-g

Tags: emacs, iterm2

On linux this sends C-M-g but on my mac in iterm2 it sends C-g.
Is there a way to configure iterm2 to send the proper sequence?

Comment: I'm not on my Mac at the moment, so can't check, but there is an option relating to key translation and meta/alt as part of the iterm2  prefeences - I just can't remember it off the top of my head, so you will need to poke around. It is there though!

Comment: I think I have that set correctly since I can use the (alt/option) key on the mac as meta key. Maybe my key sequence is wrong. What sequence is C-M-g? Is it, press ctrl-alt-g at the same time or ctrl-alt and then g?

Comment: Press them all at the same time C-M-g

Comment: Yeah, I tried that on native linux terminal emacs and that works fine but not when I ssh from the Mac using iterm2 or mac Terminal. I also tried it on native Mac emacs and it also doesn't work. C-M-q works fine but C-M-g sends C-g according to describe-key function in emacs.

Comment: There are multiple layers you need to check. 1. Verify you don't have any Mac shortcuts which are steeling the keystrokes. If you run emacs inside iterm2 and still see the problem, you can at elast rule out ssh (common to have issues with ssh and some key combos), which just leave iterm2. The iterm2 interface for preferences is quite powerful/complex, so yo will need to dig deep. I'll try to have a look if I remember next time I fire up my Mac

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not @Rahul

Comment: :( I ended up changing that key binding to something else